Should I italicize brand names and song titles?
I'm doing the final edits to my book. I often refer to music and brand names of clothing worn to set the tone. My question is when mentioning a brand name or song and artist can I italicize the brand or artist's name?
Example:

She was wearing Louis Vuitton or listening to Beyoncé's "Crazy in Love"



Italicize titles of "freestanding" publications (books, movies, perodicals, plays, vinyl records or CDs, paintings, photographs, etc.).

She read The Lord of the Rings.


Put titles of works that are published in collections and that are not commonly published on their own (articles, chapters, poems, songs, etc.) in quotation marks.

She listened to "Crazy in Love".


Capitalize brand names and personal names.

She was driving a Mercedes.
She was listenig to Beyoncé.




Your example is correct.
